# How to reference type of return value of a callback in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a generic function like this

```
function computedLastOf<T>(cb: () => T[]) : Readonly<Ref<T | undefined>> {
  return computed(() => {
    const collection = cb();
    return collection[collection.length - 1];
  });
}
```

It's a sort of macro that returns a computed(reactive) value for a collection of type T.

But notice the first `<T>`. It requires the user of this function to specify the type. It would be nice if it wasn't necessary and if it was inferred. The returned value here will always be a child of the collection that the callback returns.

Is there a way to make the typing inferred like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Afaik when calling generic functions, the generic argument will usually be inferred already, if you just omit it? In other words, writing `computedLastOf(() => [1, 2, 3])` should work.

Comment: Good tip, thanks! It's returning `Readonly<Ref<any>` in this case if I remove the type declarations though. Maybe it's an issue of `computed` that further breaks the type inference.

Comment: Most likely an issue with `computed`, yes. Sometimes, the inferrer can't handle things, and explicit type annotation is required, however, that's usually the minority of cases.

Comment: Hm, experimenting. Even if I turn the function to 

`
function lastOf(cb) {
  const collection = cb();
  return collection[collection.length - 1];
`

The result is `any`

Comment: Because now `cb` is implicitly `any` (activating "noImplicitAny" helps). Also, the generic argument is completely gone. Try E.g. `function computedLastOf<T>(cb: () => T[]) { const collection = cb(); return collection[collection.length - 1]; }`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. This works. And now it works with `computed` too. Maybe I passed in `any` through a callback before 

Feel free to post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling a generic function, it's usually possible to just omit the type argument, causing it to be inferred. This sometimes fails, but most often in far more complex scenarios, where the inferrer doesn't pick up on certain details, and infers a too wide type (valid, but not intended).

Try to call it as `computedLastOf(arg)` instead of explicitly giving it a generic argument with `computedLastOf<someType>(arg)`.